# MySQLI LOOP DATA

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to get all the records from the while loop. I'm unable to get all the rows from the query. It shows only the first row. 
Is there anything I was going wrong in my code.

```
function Connect($DB_HOST = 'localhost', $DB_USER = 'root', $DB_PASS = '', $DB_NAME = 'bodhilms')
        {
            $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME); 
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }       
            return $mysqli;
        }

    function GetCoeficient($coeficient = false, $con)
    {
       if(!$con)
        return 0;       

       $result  =   array();
       $sql[]   = "SELECT * FROM users ";       

       if($coeficient != false)
       $sql[] = "WHERE username = '".$coeficient."' ORDER BY u.id"; 

        //print_r($coeficient);
        $query  =   $con->query(implode(" ",$sql));
        //print_r($query);

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
        {
           $result[]    =   $row;
        }
        return (!empty($result))? $result : 0;
    }

    $con                        =   Connect();
    $result                     =   GetCoeficient($coeficient,$con);

    $username  =   $result[0]['username']; 
    $firstname  =   $result[0]['firstname']; 
    $lastname  =   $result[0]['lastname']; 
    $email  =   $result[0]['email'];
```

Comment: Why would you have more than one row with the same username?

Comment: You're calling `GetCourse()`, but you posted the definition of `GetCoeficient()`. Can you show the definition of `GetCourse()`?

Comment: After you call the function, you're just setting the variables from `$result[0]`, so you only get the first row.

Comment: Barmer - Sorry It wasn't course, It was GetCoeficient()

Comment: Well, you're still just setting your variables from the first row. If you want to process all the rows, write a loop, don't just access `$result[0]`.

Comment: Barmet - I wrote while loop, Now how could I fetch  all the rows. Just give me an idea, I would do myself

Comment: Like in @Gangzi's answer

Comment: Barmer - In gangzi answer, that was the data coming within the loop. I want to retrieve the values out of the loop.

Comment: Use `foreach` to loop over `$result`

Answer (score 0):

First of all,to make sure the infomation of mysql is right,like `port`.
and I wonder the code of you `$result = Getcourse($coeficient,$con);`, how the var `coeficient` come from.Then
You can try the code below:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","root","123");
$query="select * from test";
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
if ($result) {
         if($result->num_rows>0){
                  while($row =$result->fetch_array() ){
                           echo ($row[0])."<br>";
                           echo ($row[1])."<br>";
                           echo ($row[2])."<br>";
                           echo ($row[3])."<br>";
                           echo "<hr>";
                  }
         }
}else {
         echo 'failure';
}
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```